# Image Buttons Move Up and shows texts below it when hover by cursor

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create an offline website for my school project in .html and I'm trying to make something similar with the image buttons (below *"Get insurance for anything you need"*) from this website:  [here](https://www.progressive.com/)

I have image buttons that I would love to move up and would have text below it when hover by a user, just like what the image buttons of car, house, motor, boat, truck buttons do on the website I recently shared on the first paragraph.

I don't know if it is possible with just html or it should be with css or javascript.

Looking forward to your help. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, you should first try to code something yourself and then post your code here and ask for help. But it is possible to create that with `html` and `css`

Comment: You can use css or javascript or both together. Using css, you can set position absolute to your element by adding css class[className], and on the [className:hover] change the top and color of the element to what ever you want

Comment: Thanks @ShhadeSlman for your help. I am new here and will do that advice you gave me. I'm not really good at CSS as I am still a student but I have a few ideas on it. Will give it a try. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/156/

**HTML**

```
<div class="box">
   <a href="#">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x100" alt="">

    <div class="hover-content">
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
    </div>
   </a>   
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
 h3 {
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.box {
    width: 20%;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 100px;
}

.hover-content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
    z-index: 1;
}

.box:hover .hover-content{
    top: 50px;
    opacity: 1;
}

.box img {
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
    z-index: 2;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.box:hover img {
    transform: translateY(-50px);
}
```

Comment: Wow! You nailed it! Thank you very much! I'm so glad to join the stackoverflow family. I don't know how to integrate CSS, should I put <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ before the  h3 {
    margin-top: 5px;
} ...yet again, thank you for your amazing help!

Comment: You're welcome. Check out this http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp

Comment: Thank you very much once again!